# kivy-designer : No module named 'kivy.adapters'

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

гугл не дает решения этой проблемы. я так понял что модуль kivy.adapters устарел, но я не понимаю как решить проблему.

```
C:\Users\михаил\kivy-designer>python -m designer
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\михаил\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-06-24_15.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.1.17
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.1.9
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.1.12
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.1.22
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Python37-32\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 NVIDIA 430.39'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'GeForce GTX 760/PCIe/SSE2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 NVIDIA'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
     "__main__", mod_spec)
   File "C:\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
     exec(code, run_globals)
   File "C:\Users\михаил\kivy-designer\designer\__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
     from designer.app import DesignerApp
   File "C:\Users\михаил\kivy-designer\designer\app.py", line 12, in <module>
     from designer.components.designer_content import DesignerContent
   File "C:\Users\михаил\kivy-designer\designer\components\designer_content.py", line 5, in <module>
     from designer.uix.py_code_input import PyScrollView
   File "C:\Users\михаил\kivy-designer\designer\uix\py_code_input.py", line 3, in <module>
     from designer.uix.completion_bubble import CompletionBubble
   File "C:\Users\михаил\kivy-designer\designer\uix\completion_bubble.py", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.adapters.listadapter import ListAdapter
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.adapters'
```

Comment: Либо переписать код без использования адаптеров, либо установить старую версию, к примеру `pip install "kivy<1.11" `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kivy Designer закрыт, полон багов и никем не поддерживается, там же ясно написано!

Comment: Спасибо за информацию! Вопрос закрыт